# Difference of elements in PySpark list with one or two elements

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe which has a list with either one element or two elements. When there are two elements in the list, they are not ordered by ascending or descending orders.

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| version| timestamp| list  |
+--------+-----+----|-------+
| v1     |2012-01-10| [5,2] |
| v1     |2012-01-11| [2,5] |
| v1     |2012-01-12| [3,2] |
| v2     |2012-01-12| [2]   |
| v2     |2012-01-11| [1,2] |
| v2     |2012-01-13| [1]   |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I want to take difference betweeen the first and the second elements of the list (when there are two elements) and have that as another column (`diff`). When there is only one element in the list, I want to put zero in output. Here is an example of the output that I want.

```
+--------+----------+-------+-------+
| version| timestamp| list  |  diff | 
+--------+-----+----|-------+-------+
| v1     |2012-01-10| [5,2] |   3   |
| v1     |2012-01-11| [2,5] |  -3   |
| v1     |2012-01-12| [3,2] |   1   |
| v2     |2012-01-12| [2]   |   0   |
| v2     |2012-01-11| [1,2] |  -1   |
| v2     |2012-01-13| [1]   |   0   |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+
```

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400653/difference-of-elements-in-list-in-pyspark) which I asked before, but is not exactly the same.

**How can I do this using PySpark?**

I am also open to the use of UDFs to get my intended output in case one needs that.

Approaches without UDF and those which are based on UDF are both welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: try: `df.selectExpr("*","IF(list[1] is NULL,0,list[0]-list[1]) as diff").show()`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to **`@Shu's`** answer from earlier, just add a **`when/otherwise`** clause to that by checking **`size`** of array.

```
df.withColumn("diff", F.when(F.size('list')==2, F.expr("""transform(array(list),x-> x[0]-x[1])""")[0])\
                       .otherwise(F.lit(0))).show()

#+------+----+
#|  list|diff|
#+------+----+
#|[5, 2]|   3|
#|[2, 5]|  -3|
#|   [2]|   0|
#+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a `udf` like so

#### Example data

```
data = [
    ('v1', [5, 2],),
    ('v1', [2, 5],),
    ('v1', [3, 2],),
    ('v2', [2],),
    ('v2', [1, 2],),
    ('v2', [1],),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['version', 'list'])
```

#### Solution

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# UDF definition
find_diff = udf(lambda a: reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, a), IntegerType()) 

(
    df.
        withColumn(
            'diff',
            find_diff('list')
        ).
        show(truncate=False)
)

+-------+------+----+                                                           
|version|list  |diff|
+-------+------+----+
|v1     |[5, 2]|3   |
|v1     |[2, 5]|-3  |
|v1     |[3, 2]|1   |
|v2     |[2]   |2   |
|v2     |[1, 2]|-1  |
|v2     |[1]   |1   |
+-------+------+----+
```